# How can I temporarily set a folder as the workspace in VS Code to run specific configurations?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a tree structure with multiple different projects in Visual Studio Code (VS Code). Each project is in a separate folder within the tree structure.

Is there a way to make one of these folders the current workspace folder ad hoc, so that I can easily run the configuration specific to that folder?

Is there a way to designate a folder as the active workspace folder temporarily, so that I can execute the configurations specific to that folder without modifying the overall workspace settings?

I've come across the concept of [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#%5C_multiroot-workspaces) in VS Code, but I'm not sure if it allows me to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make one of these folders the current workspace folder ad hoc, so that I can easily run the configuration specific to that folder?

As far as I'm aware, the easiest you'll get is using `File: Open File...` (if you've never opened the folder / workspace) before, or using `File: Open Recent...` (these are command palette commands and both of which have keybindings, which you can find in the command palette. They're also both available under the "File" menu item)

---

> I've come across the concept of multi-root workspaces in VS Code, but I'm not sure if it allows me to achieve what I need.

Multi-root workspaces allow you to create a flat list of workspace roots that are all open at once. You can set configuration for all workspaces by putting it in the .code-workspace file, or per-workspace-root by putting it in their `.vscode/settings.json` files.